# What number should be placed instead of the question mark?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

There is a specific and common relationship between the numbers of each rectangular shape.

What number should be placed instead of the question mark?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is

> 41

Reason

> Numbers in any given rectangle form an AP. In top left one difference is 5, in top right it is 4, in bottom left it is 15 and in bottom right it is 15. So number is 26+15 = 41